# how to use nullif() in a query in a php form

Tags: php, postgresql, nullif

I try to import a csv file in a table in PostgreSQL 13 and php form (**beginner**).
There are two foreign keys integer type in the table, one can be empty. So when I import the file I have the common message `invalid input syntax for type integer` for one of them.
Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703606/insert-null-into-a-postgresql-db-via-php-when-a-date-field-is-empty), NullIf() function seems to be a simple solution.

I can't find the right way to use it in :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO activite.us (numus, gidgeo, gidaxe)
        VALUES ('".$getData[0]."','".$getData[10]."', NULLIF('".$getData[11]."', '') " ;
```

The foreign key is the last variable.

- I tried to replace second arg with NULL ;
- I tried `'NULLIF("...")'` and some others false combo.

How to fix that ?
Thanks.

Comment: (Possible) side note: Do not use string interpolation or concatenation to get values into SQL queries. That's error prone and might make your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: This depends on what the syntax error actually is, so please show the entire error message in your question. Pretty sure `NULLIF` is not the answer.  A best practices is to create a table that has all `varchar` fields and import into that and then do clean up on/before transfer to final table.

Answer (score 0):

(Even if PDO would be better,) an answer is

```
NULLIF('".$getData[11]."', '')::integer)
```