# How to convert empty to null in PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, null

I have some columns type int, but value is empty. So I want to convert empty to null when I insert to database.
I use code:

```
function toDB($string) {
    if ($string == '' || $string == "''") {
        return 'null';
    } else {
        return "'$string'";
    }
}

//age,month,year is type integer.
$name="Veo ve";
$age='10';
$month='';
$year='';
    $query="Insert Into tr_view(name,age,month,year) values ({toDB($name)},{toDB($age)},{toDB($month)},{toDB($year)})
 $db->setQuery($query);
 $result= $db->query();
```

But it show error:

```
 pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near ";" LINE 153: {toDB(10)}, ^ in...
```

Why?

Comment: You cannot insert '' into an int, only an integer or a null.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While Erwin's answer about `NULLIF` is *awesome*, it doesn't address your syntax error.

Let's take a look at the query:

```
$query="Insert Into tr_view(name,age,month,year) values ({toDB($name)},{toDB($age)},{toDB($month)},{toDB($year)})
```

Earlier you defined a function called `toDB`.  Unfortunately the syntax you are using here is *not* how to call a function from within a double-quoted string, so the curlies and `toDB(` bits are still being passed through.  There are two alternatives:

1. Concatenation using `.`:

   ```
   $query='insert Into tr_view(name,age,month,year) values (' . toDB($name) . ',' . toDB($age) . ',' . toDB($month) . ',' . toDB($year) . ')')
   ```
2. You can interpolate a callable *variable* into a double-quoted string thusly:

   ```
   $fn = 'toDB';
   $query="Insert Into tr_view(name,age,month,year) values ({$fn($name)},{$fn($age)},{$fn($month)},{$fn($year)})";
   ```

The first is clear and sane, the second is vague to the unfamiliar and downright *insane*.

However, you still should not be assembling input like this.  You still may be vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  You should be using [prepared statements with parameterized placeholders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

The Postgres extension uses [`pg_prepare`](http://php.net/pg_prepare) for this.  They have the distinct advantage of, say, allowing you to pass a PHP `null` instead of having to worry about all of that null-detection and quoting.

If you insist on keeping `toDB` as-is, consider adding one of the `pg_escape_` functions, like [`pg_escape_string`](http://php.net/pg_escape_string), to the thing that builds quoted strings.

Answer (score 93):

There is the [**`NULLIF()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) function:

```
SELECT NULLIF(var, '');
```

If `var` equals the 2nd parameter, you get `NULL` instead.
The example replaces the empty string `''` with `NULL`.

There is **no "empty string" for the type integer**. Both parameters must be of compatible type, so sanitize your input in PHP.

If you did not define a column default, you can also **just omit the column** in the `INSERT` command and it will be filled with `NULL` (which is the default `DEFAULT`).

Check if the parameter is empty in PHP and don't include the column in the `INSERT` command if it is.

Or use the **PHP literal NULL** instead like Quassnoi demonstrates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1027549/939860).

#### The rest only makes sense for string types

To **make absolutely sure**, nobody can enter an empty string add a `CHECK` constraint to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE tr_view
ADD CONSTRAINT tr_view_age_not_empty CHECK (age <> '');
```

To **avoid exceptions** caused by this, you could add a trigger that fixes input automatically:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_tr_view_avoid_empty()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF NEW.age = '' THEN
      NEW.age := NULL;
   END IF;

   IF NEW.month = '' THEN
      NEW.month := NULL;
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_view_avoid_empty
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON tr_view
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.age = '' OR NEW.month = '')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_tr_view_avoid_empty();
```

Comment: I know that thank you comments are discouraged, but I'll go ahead and say thank you.