# Substituting value in empty field after using split_part

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, natural-sort

I have two columns, `id integer` and `version text`. I am trying to convert the strings in `version` into integers so that I may select the maximum (most recent) version of the id.

However, the the first instance of the `id` stores itself as the `version`. Example:

```
id | version
---+--------
10 | '10'
```

as opposed to:

```
id | version
---+--------
10 | '10-0'
```

Additional rows follow the convention id: 10, version: 10-1. Etc.

How can I accomplish this? I have tried `split_part()` and cast as `int`. However, `split_part(version, "-", 2)` will return what looks like an empty string. I have tried running this using a `COALESCE(splitpart..., '0')` to no avail as it tried to read the empty field returned by the field index 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the combination of [coalesce() and nullif(),](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) example:

```
with my_table(version) as (
values
    ('10'), ('10-1'), ('10-2')
)

select 
    version, 
    split_part(version, '-', 1)::int as major, 
    coalesce(nullif(split_part(version, '-', 2), ''), '0')::int as minor
from my_table

 version | major | minor 
---------+-------+-------
 10      |    10 |     0
 10-1    |    10 |     1
 10-2    |    10 |     2
(3 rows)
```

Comment: coalesce(nullif(split_part(version, '-', 2), ''), '0')::int  ---- Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[**`split_part()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) returns the empty string (`''`) - not `NULL` - when the part to be returned is empty or non-existent. That's why [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) does *nothing* here. And the empty string (`''`) has no representation as `integer` value, hence it throws an error when trying to cast it.

The shortest way in this example should be [**`GREATEST(split_part( ... ) , '0')`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) before casting, since the empty string sorts before any other non-empty string or even NULL (in any locale). Then use `DISTINCT ON ()` to get the row with the "biggest" `version` for each `id`.

#### Test setup

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   id      integer NOT NULL
 , version text    NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
     (10, '10-2')
   , (10, '10-1')
   , (10, '10')      -- missing subversion
   , (10, '10-111')  -- multi-digit number
   , (11, '11-1')
   , (11, '11-0')    -- proper '0'
   , (11, '11-')     -- missing subversion but trailing '-'
   , (11, '11-2');
```

#### Solutions

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY id, GREATEST(split_part(version, '-', 2), '0')::int DESC;
```

Result:

```
 id | version 
----+---------
 10 | 10-111
 11 | 10-2
```

***Or*** you *could* also use `NULLIF` and use `NULLS LAST` (in descending order) to sort:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY id, NULLIF(split_part(version, '-', 2), '')::int DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Same result.

***Or*** a more explicit `CASE` statement:

```
CASE WHEN split_part(version, '-', 2) = '' THEN '0' ELSE split_part(version, '-', 2) END
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5c0c9e3ff1642d369d326ed14522b993)*

Related:

- [Order varchar string as numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502505/order-varchar-string-as-numeric/8502570#8502570)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)
- [How to convert empty to null in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035883/how-to-convert-empty-to-null-in-postgresql/14035890#14035890)

Comment: `greatest(val, '0')::int` is usually slower than `coalesce(nullif(val, ''), '0')::int`.

Comment: @klin: True, if only slightly. Typically `CASE` is fastest. Or just `NULLIF` without `COALESCE` in this case. `GREATEST` is shortest / simplest here.

Answer (score 2):

To get around the version strings which have no hyphen, you can use a `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN version LIKE '%-%'
     THEN SPLIT_PART(version, '-', 2)::int
     ELSE 0 END
```

The basic idea is to use the version number, cast to an int, when a hyphen is present, but otherwise to assume that the version is zero if the hyphen is absent.

With this hurdle out of the way, your query now just reduces to a `ROW_NUMBER()` query.  Here, the partition is the `id`, and the ordering is given using the above `CASE` expression for the version.

```
SELECT
    t.id, t.version
FROM
(
    SELECT
        id,
        CASE WHEN version LIKE '%-%'
             THEN version
             ELSE version || '-0' END AS version,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                           ORDER BY
                               CASE WHEN version LIKE '%-%'
                                    THEN SPLIT_PART(version, '-', 2)::int
                                    ELSE 0 END DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY t.id;
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thank you for your solution!